# Making menu appear in center

Tags: css

I am trying to bring the menu bar in the center. I have tried adding a `text-align:centre;` but it does not work. [Here](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/natali/) is the website.Please guide me. Thanks.

```
<nav style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 22px;text-align:center;"> <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>">NATALI-D | Fashion Stylist</a></h1>   
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation
```

-->

Answer (score 2):

The parent `ul` doesn't have a `text-align: center;` and has no `width: 100%;`

Try:

```
ul.nav-menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The container (UL) is not 100%, so its not bigger than the two LI. Use width 100% on the UL, and then use `text-align: center;` to make it center.

```
ul.nav-menu, div.nav-menu > ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```